# Class constructors cannot be invoked without 'new'

Tags: javascript, nodejs, npm, es6

Estaba intentando hacer un paquete de `npm`, algo sencillo:

```
class Hello {
    constructor(world){
        this._world = world | 'world';
    }

    world(){
        return this._world;
    }
}

module.exports = Hello;
```

Luego haciendo pruebas quería inicializarlo de la siguiente manera:

```
var Hello = require('Hello')('world');
console.log(Hello.world());
```

Pero me devolvió el siguiente error

> Class constructor Hello cannot be invoked without 'new'

¿Qué debo cambiar en mi módulo y/o clase para inicializarlo de esa forma?

Y **no** tener que realizar algo así:

```
var Hello = require('Hello');
var hello = new Hello('world');
console.log(hello.world());
```

Comment: Una opción (fea) es `var Hello = new (require('Hello'))('world');`

Comment: @PabloLozano lo solucioné como dices, ¿no deberías ponerlo como una respuesta? ¿por qué dices que feo? a mi me parece práctico, ¿de qué otra manera más limpia o elegante podría realizarlo?

Answer (score 2):

Para ello necesitas instanciar la clase desde el módulo aceptando el parámetro con que la quieres utilizar. Basta con cambiar la línea de exportado:

```
...
module.exports = mundo => new Hello(mundo)
```

Comment: podrias agregar una descripción de como llegaste a esa solución

Comment: Hecho, gracias.

Comment: Realicé lo que dices pero no me funcionó

Comment: Funciona, pero creo que hay un error en el constructor de la clase. En vez de un OR booleano "|" debes usar un OR lógico "||". Al menos si lo que quieres que muestre es "world".